# Statistics in an array

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the following data:

```
data = {{0.73, 0.75}, {0.70, 0.67}, {0.76}, {0.84}};
```

where the elements of data (data[[i]]) vary in length.
I need to make statistics over data[[i]]. Eg I want to have the Mean and the Standard Deviation per element.
How to do this with a simple rule?

Comment: `Mean /@ data`? `Table[Mean[elem], {elem, data}]`?

Comment: over rows or collumns? For instance, the StandardDeviation of data[[3]] is nonsens, one number has no SD.

Comment: indeed. how to program that when there is no StandardDeviation, I get a 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define a helper function that returns mean and standard deviation, but if there is only one element in the list, it returns 0 for the SD, then map it on your data:

```
f = (Through[{Mean, (If[Length[#] == 1, 0, StandardDeviation[#]] &)}[#]] &);
f /@ data

(* Out: {{0.74, 0.0141421}, {0.685, 0.0212132}, {0.76, 0}, {0.84, 0}} *)
```

Answer (score 5):

[Map](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) applies *f* to each element on the first level in *expr*.

I suggest you define a new function *describeData*, which performs the 'statistics' you need. Then you simply do:

```
Map[describeData, data]
```

For example:

```
describeData = Function[{data},{Mean[data], StandardDeviation[data]}]
Grid[Map[describeData, data]]
```

You will be able to easily extend this function, in case you need additional information about the data (e.g. `Histogram[]` or `Min[]` and `Max[]`).

Comment: this works. How to avoid errors with StandardDeviation when data[[i]] is just one element?

Comment: Yes, for example, you could add an `If[]` statement. See MarcoB's answer.